# Error processing request - List of values, Oracle Application Express (APEX)

Tags: oracle, apex

I am trying to delete a List of values from shared components. But every time I tried to press delete I get an error: Error processing request. List is not used anywhere, it is not subscribed to any other list, and any other list is not subscribed to this list. Is anybody aware of the cause of this error?
[Delete](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xeKt4.png)

Comment: Did you try to log off, turn the browser down and start again?

Comment: Yes, I also tried to clear browser data...

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Hi, I there is no code to provide because this happens on multiple different LOV in the same app but other apps are working fine, so I cannot reproduce the problem. I just asked to see if someone else also encountered this problem also.